# Как сложить два объекта одного класса?

Tags: python, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать сложение двух объектов одного класса, используя перегрузку операторов. Получилось пока что только сложить объект с числом.

```
#сложение int и объекта
class fff:
    v = 10
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.a)
    def __add__(self,v):
        return self.a + v


f1 = fff(1)
f2 = fff(5)
v=10

print(f1, f2, f1+v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Fff:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Fff):
            return Fff(self.value + other.value)
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            return Fff(self.value + other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented


a = Fff(3)
b = Fff(5)
print(a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class fff:
    v = 10
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.a)
    def __add__(self,v):
        if isinstance(v, fff):
            return self.a + v.a
        else:
            return self.a + v


f1 = fff(1)
f2 = fff(5)
v=10

print(f1, f2, f1+v)
```

> 1 5 11

```
print(f1+f2)
```

> 6